# isset($_COOKIE) is not working

Tags: php

I am using the function set cookie to set (id) cookie like so:

```
$cookie_id = $insert_userid;
setcookie("id", $cookie_id, time() + 31556926, '/', 'www.example.com');
```

The code above is working fine. I am checking the setting with firefox and the correct cookie is there.
Now on my other pages on my webiste I want to check if the cookie is set.
I am using this code to redirect if the cookie is not set.
I am getting redirected in both ways weather the cookie is set or not.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['id'])){
//do something.
}else{
header('Location: login.php');
}
    ?>
```

how do I fix this problem ?

Var dump result is :

```
array(4) { ["link"]=> string(43) "http://www.zzz.com/zzz" ["__unam"]=> string(30) "a5caeed-1385397a335-7fca86ad-2" ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "6khzzzzzzzzjd51i6hamm0" ["id"]=> string(10) "zzzzzzzzzz" }
```

Update: I am not checking the cookie from the same page I crated it.

Comment: Is it just me or are you not closing the }else{ ?

Comment: `var_dump($_COOKIE);` and post the results...

Comment: I have the code closed in the original script. this is just for demonstration.

Comment: On a side note: this seems spooky... can you reassure me if I manually set a cookie 'id' for your site, with a random id, that I cannot see material for which a user normally would have to log in?

Comment: @Wrikken: It's just code for demonstration, as said up.

Comment: OK, (1) consider me reassured, (2) there is a problem in your actual code that is not in this test code, as demonstrated by the `var_dump`.

Comment: Dumb question, but are you actually serving the cookie from www.example.com?  (Or whatever domain you're using.)  If not, you won't be able to read the cookie.  Note that the domain has to either match *exactly* (that is, www.example.com, **not** example.com), unless you specify .example.com (with a dot in front), in which case the bare domain and all subdomains (that is, example.com and www.example.com) would match also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help find the problem, try this:

```
var_dump($_COOKIE['id']); exit;
```

Put that before the `if`. Ideally, you should see the cookie's value. If you see `NULL`, then the cookie is not being passed.

If it's not being passed, try just `var_dump($_COOKIE); exit;` and see if you get an array and, if so, if there is an `id` key.

Make sure that the cookie is being sent, check with Developer Tools or whatever your browser's equivalent is.